# How to change the default port for Global Catalog Server?

Tags: active-directory

I would like to change the default port for my global catalog server from 3268 to something else, is there a way i can do this? GC is running on Windows server 2012

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. It's a well known port that's expected to be static.